# Are these smooth bump functions $\in C_{0}^{\infty}(-1,\ 1)$? $f(x) = \left(1+\exp\left(\frac{1-2|x|}{x^2-|x|}\right)\right)^{-1}$ and related

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, functional-equations, smooth-functions, delay-differential-equations

**Are these smooth bump functions $\in C_{0}^{\infty}(-1,\ 1)$?  $f(x) = \left(1+\exp\left(\frac{1-2|x|}{x^2-|x|}\right)\right)^{-1}$ and related**

Trying to find an answer to [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4421898/909869), I took a function from [this answer to other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/101484/909869) and modified it to make:

1. $$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{\frac{1-2\ |x|}{x^2-|x|}}},\quad x\in(-1,\ 1)$$ which look like a [smooth bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function), but since it contain absolute value functions within, so I don't know if at some derivative it will fail to be class $C^\infty$.

Also, by taking the derivative of $f(x)$ I found that it looses its [flat top](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function) so it cannot be solving some [Delay differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation) as the asked in the [mentioned question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4421898/909869): $f'(x)=2\ f(2x+1)-2\ f(2x-1),\,f(0)=1,\,x\in(-1,\ 1)$ which required the "new lobes" to keep the form of the original function. So by playing with functions I found [this in Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vrny5s9rc2):

2. $$q(x) = \frac{1+e^{\frac{-1}{|x|^{\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{2\pi}}}}}{1+e^{\frac{1-2\ |x|}{x^2-|x|}}},\quad x\in(-1,\ 1)$$ which I know beforehand don't solve the presented delayed differential equation since its derivative maximum is not $2$, but at least it keep at some extent the flat top shape.

[image: Desmos example]

**So I would like to know if these functions $f(x)$ and $q(x)$ are smooth bump functions.**

**Bonus track:** There is a "simple" Delay Differential Equation (DDE) solved by $q(x)$?, I am trying to find something similar to the scaled/displaced version of the [Fabius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function) that [solves the DDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4421898/909869): $\varphi'(x)=2\varphi(2x+1)-2\varphi(2x-1)$ when $|x|\leq 1$.

*PS: in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/285931/82135) you could see a comparison of a numerical implementation of the Fabius function $\text{FabiusF}(x+1)$ against $q(x)$ and fit relatively good for $|x|<1$.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately after playing in Desmos I noted the derivatives of $g(x) = \left(1+\exp\left(\frac{1-2|x|}{x^2-1}\right)\right)$ start to jump near $\pm 1$, and after check in [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5B1%2F%281%2Be%5E%28%281-2%7Cx%7C%29%2F%28x%5E2-%7Cx%7C%29%29%29%2C%7Bx%2C4%7D%5D) for its 4th derivative I saw some Dirac's Delta Function (and derivatives of it) have rise, so it is not a smooth bump function class $C_0^\infty(-1,\ 1)$. Nevertheless, at least is gives a "good" fit to the Fabius function $F(x+1)$ as it can be seen in this [other question](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5B1%2F%281%2Be%5E%28%281-2%7Cx%7C%29%2F%28x%5E2-%7Cx%7C%29%29%29%2C%7Bx%2C4%7D%5D)